# Structure of X-expression in Racket

Tags: racket

Racket represents XML data as an X-expression: http://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/index.html?q=#(def._((lib._xml/private/xexpr-core..rkt)._xexpr~3f))
which is defined as follows:

```
xexpr    =      string
        |       (list symbol (list (list symbol string) ...) xexpr ...)
        |       (cons symbol (list xexpr ...))
        |       symbol
        |       valid-char?
        |       cdata
        |       misc
```

In the second alternative, why is it `(list symbol string)` and not `(cons symbol string)` ? Is there any specific reason to use `list` instead of `cons` ? If not, would there be any advantage in using `cons` instead of `list` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really just a preference on the part of the X-expression designers, probably to mirror `let`'s syntax (which also uses proper lists only).

With `(list symbol string)`, you'd represent `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>` as:

```
(a ((href "http://stackoverflow.com/")) "Stack Overflow")
```

whereas with `(cons symbol string)`, it'd be:

```
(a ((href . "http://stackoverflow.com/")) "Stack Overflow")
```

Some would consider the "dot" an ugly thing to see.

Comment: re the sub-question _"If not, would there be any advantage in using cons instead of list ?"_ -- Yes; not having a null cons cell would save RAM. But arguably that's outweighed by the readability and "type-ability" of not needing to dot everything.